# Embedded styles causing hidden divs

Tags: html, css, webkit

So I have had the unpleasant of adopting a project... Anyway, there is a div on the site that displays some information, and for some reason there is an embedded style somewhere that is causing it to `display: none;` I used Google Chrome's Web Developer plugin to disable all embedded styles and it works fine then. As I inspect the element I can see the style that is causing it, but when i try and disable the CSS property display, it disables but doesn't create that strike-through on the property. I implicitly put an inline style of `display: block !important;` and still no good. There also doesn't seem to be any reference to a location where that style comes from, doesn't say User Agent Stylesheet, not a reference to any other stylesheet.

The funny thing is, IE it works fine. The div shows perfectly...  Firefox, and Safari cause the same problem which led me to think it might actually be a WebKit bug. Just need some more light on this maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The div's class was advert_container and one of my my browser plugins was AdBlock and this caused the div to be removed...

Answer (score -1):

Were you referencing this display:block !important, inline with the html element, or in some style sheet somewhere?

The closer the CSS attribute is to your problem div this should apply this. Also referencing !important generally overrules other CSS attributes, however if the other CSS attribute is more specific, it could also be the reason why this is getting overruled.

If you are in developer tools, and get the intended effect, you should just copy the css it created, and paste that in your html page.

Comment: Yes, its is in order of specificity. But nothing is more specific than an inline style. See sure enough i could just copy that selector and set it to `display: block;` and that works fine. But i'm concerned as to why there is this mysterious selector that appears only on WebKit browsers...